# How to capturing auxcodes using jtapi for avaya phones?

Tags: avaya, jtapi

I am implementing on CTI application which will monitor all events of agent. Currently I am having trouble in getting auxcodes events. By check the agent state i get the auxcodes but i want an event for auxcode changes so that immediately i can get the auxcodes.

Answer (score 1):

You may extract an Avaya extension of Agent from the AgentEvent and the get the AgentStateInfo from it.

```
Agent agent = agentTerminalEvent.getAgent();
LucentV5AgentStateInfo lasi = (LucentV5AgentStateInfo)((LucentAgent)agent).getStateInfo();
int state = lasi.state;
int rc = lasi.reasonCode;
int wm = lasi.workMode;
```

(if this is what you are looking for)

EDIT :

It seems that you can monitor full agent activty by monitoring the ACDAddress with ACDAddressListener.

ae-services-jtapi-programmers-guide-6_3_1.pdf Appendix A Page 60 :

> To completely monitor  agent activity, please use an 
>   ACDAddressListener

OLD (may be outdated):

> **BUT** : Other AgentTerminalEvents or ACDAddressEvents then Logon and Logoff are not produced if the change of the agent's state is not done
>   by the JTAPI itself.
>
> That means if an agent changes his state to NOT_READY using his phone
>   you will not receive an AgentTerminalEvent.
>
> If that state change is done by your program (Agent.setState...) then
>   you will receive an event.

Comment: Thanks. I used ACDAddressListener but when user changes auxcodes no even is fied. The above code will definately give auxcode but then this need to check after some given interval to get auxcode.